Problem with GNOME Terminal 3.54.0
After updating a Raspberry Pi 5 (8GB) from Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10 GNOME Terminal 3.54.0 fails on the command
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage
# Failed to parse arguments: Too many arguments

Since I want to use the class option I am using X11 as my Windowing System.  Under 24.04 with GNOME Terminal 3.52.0 this command works.  If I use
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ gnome-terminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage 

the command works, but I want to use the class option to make the indicator dot in the Dash attach to the correct icon. To show what I'm using here is the full Sage.desktop file
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
StartupNotify=false
Icon[en_US]=sage-terminal-dark
Icon=sage-terminal-dark
Name=Sage
Name[en_US]=Sage
#Use following line if logging in with Ubuntu on Xorg
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage
#Use following line if logging in with Ubuntu and Wayland
#Exec=env GTK_BACKEND=x11 gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage
StartupWMClass=SageTerminal
Actions=SageDocumentation;
Path=/home/rquint/Sage

[Desktop Action SageDocumentation]
Name=Sage Documentation
Exec=firefox /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/local/share/doc/sage/html/en/index.html
OnlyShowIn=Unity


OP reported that the issue is fixed on Wayland and Xorg after applying my patch.
Note that my patch, even though it appears to fix this specific issue, might not be perfect.
Someone on Launchpad claimed that it's wrong and that it doesn't cover some edge cases - and they may very well be right - I'm not familiar with the original script nor I've delved too much into it in order to fully understand it.
So use it if you need to use --class, don't expect it to be perfect and at the same time don't bother remembering you've applied it as, once the issue is solved at the package level (either using my patch / an equivalent one / a better one), gnome-terminal will be updated along with the package.
Here's the patch, you can save it to, say ~/gnome-terminal.patch and apply it with sudo patch "$(which gnome-terminal)" ~/gnome-terminal.patch:
--- /usr/bin/gnome-terminal 2024-09-16 15:44:46.000000000 +0200
+++ gnome-terminal  2024-10-18 19:04:30.926428246 +0200
@@ -39,10 +39,8 @@
 
     def server_appeared(self, con, name, owner):
         # start gnome-terminal now
-         Gio.Subprocess.new(['/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real',
-                             '--app-id', name] +
-                             self.args,
-                             Gio.SubprocessFlags.NONE)
+         self.args[1:1]=['--app-id', name]
+         Gio.Subprocess.new(self.args, Gio.SubprocessFlags.NONE)
 
     def spawn_terminal_server(self, name, cls):
         args = ['/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server',

I'm unclear on the state of using gnome-terminal.real in place of gnome-terminal; I'll leave that method down below in case you want to try that instead of applying the patch, it certainly fixes gnome-terminal not starting up when fed --class, however I'm unsure on whether that will result in the class being applied correctly.

TLDR: It's a bug. For the time being, you can use:
gnome-terminal.real --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage

or alias gnome-terminal to gnome-terminal.real for convenience:
alias gnome-terminal=gnome-terminal.real


I found a bug report for this on Launchpad, which is also mentioned in the comments to the upstream commit that broke this; however this bug shows up because of how Ubuntu invokes the actual gnome-terminal executable (gnome-terminal is actually a Python script which invokes gnome-terminal.real), so the issue is definetly on Ubuntu's side.
I tried fiddling with the Python script to see if I could fix it, but I couldn't find a better fix than having it bypass command-line argument parsing entirely (within the time that I was willing to spend on fixing the script at least - if I feel like doing that I'll take a look at it again), however for the time being bypassing the wrapper script altoghether works:
gnome-terminal.real --class=Foo -- /usr/bin/sh

doesn't complain and spawns a new terminal instance running sh.
Until this is fixed, you may find convenient to alias gnome-terminal to gnome-terminal.real:
alias gnome-terminal=gnome-terminal.real


Yes it's this. OP please nag Ubuntu folks to fix it.

@egmont And don't pile in on GNOME Terminal's Gitlab. It's our fault, not theirs ;)

Would gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -x /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage also work?

@muru No, same problem, but with an added message related to -x's deprecation. They're doing something specifically with the --class argument (in the arg-parsing function there's a comment that goes like swallow these arguments, before parser.agg_arguments() is invoked with a --class argument). Then other shananigans, but I didn't go deeper than this, there's an if statement that evaluates cmdargs.disable_factory and self.name which, if set to 1, will skip any further processing and straight invoke the the executable, but I'm not sure of the implications of going that route.

Hmm... What happens if you remove the self.args.insert(0, "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real") line? Going by @egmont's comment on LP, that extra argument might be what's causing the problem.

@muru Yup, that fixes it, thanks! I had missed egmont's comment on Launchpad... I wrote a patch to fix it

@muru Nope, no good, just kidding. It breaks launching gnome-terminal if there's not a server instance running already (i.e. you can't launch it unless you have an instance already opened). Both Ctrl + Alt + T and launching it from the dock break if I patch the script, and launching gnome-terminal from Xterm shows Python throwing exceptions. There's more to this than just that line

@muru & kos, Thanks a lot for working on a fix! I admit I haven't looked at the wrapper script and didn't start to track it down. I thought Ubuntu maintainers would do it, but unfortunately this bugreport fell through the cracks for them. If you have a fix and post it on LP I'd be happy to write a heads-up email to the Debian/Ubuntu package maintainer guy who will hopefully release an update.

@egmont I'll take another stab at it later / tomorrow, the thing is obviously it needs to be a proper fix, and I'm not familiar with everything that's going on in that script... But ff I manage to fix it and I'm confident enough it's a good fix I'll post a patch here, on LP and ping you to let you know. Thanks!

Turns out OP did indeed nag Ubuntu folks even before I asked him: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/2084851

@egmont I linked the previous issue and confirmed the bug, let's see what happens

Using gnome-terminal.real doesn't quite work.  Although gnome-terminal.real --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-10.4/sage runs sage, xprop WM_CLASSreports WM_CLASS(STRING) = "org.gnome.Terminal", "Gnome-terminal" instead of the expected WM_CLASS(STRING) = "org.gnome.Terminal", "SageTerminal"

@RichardQuint I'm not sure what's the deal with that, I suppose that should work? I'll ask egmont, I posted a (possible) partial patch on Launchpad, but if there's something more involving gnome-terminal itself...

@egmont Could you please review Richard Quint's comment? It appears as though WM_CLASS isn't set even when invoking gnome-terminal.real with --class directly; I tested this on Wayland (OP appears to be on Xorg) and I get the same if I inspect the window's attribute using Alt + F2 / lg. Are we missing something? Or is this an issue with gnome-terminal itself?

Thanks all.  Tried using the patch posted by @kos at pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/yyCJCwgs3C but the command sudo patch "$(which gnome-terminal) ~/gnome-terminal.patch" just hung.

@RichardQuint My bad, I misquoted the command. sudo patch "$(which gnome-terminal)" ~/gnome-terminal.patch. However it'll probably just fix gnome-terminal not swallowing --class, it didn't fix the WM_CLASS issue for me on Wayland. I asked egmont if there's an issue with gnome-terminal.real, cause that looks like it should work?

@kos I had the same result on Xorg.  Still didn't fix the WM_CLASS issue.

At first glimpse, I can confirm that --class doesn't seem to work for me either. A quick search among gnome-terminal's issue suggests that it's deprecated / phased out intentionally with something else available, but I'm not familiar with the reasons / details / new solution and I'm too sleepy now to understand the story.

After some more Ubuntu updates, gnome-terminal with @kos's patch is working correctly.  I won't close this yet since I want to wait to see if something else has broken.

@RichardQuint So WM_CLASS is set correctly? On Wayland that's still broken, and it might be due to gnome-terminal itself, we don't really know; but if you're sure that it now works on Xorg I'll update my answer (by the way someone on Launchpad is claiming that my patch and egmont's refactored patch are wrong - they may be right, I don't know, so I suggest trying (and using) gnome-terminal.real instead (if that also happens to work))

@kos On both the Pi and an Intel machine everything now works after applying your patch  under both Wayland and Xorg (assuming the Exec line in the desktop file has env GTK_BACKEND=x11 when needed).  My desktop file is too long to include as a comment so I'll edit the original question to include it.

@RichardQuint Thanks for reporting back, however it doesn't appear to be working for me on Wayland, even when setting GTK_BACKEND to x11 (and with not working I mean: WM_CLASS is still org.gnome.Terminal). I updated my answer since you reported it as working but I'm curious, what does lg run in th Alt + F2 prompt report for the terminal's WM_CLASS on your end?

@kos Here's the system info and the output from lg
rquint@Iphegenia:~$ uname -a
Linux Iphegenia 6.11.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 14 13:19:59 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
rquint@Iphegenia:~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 47.0
rquint@Iphegenia:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
iPython:rquint/Sage
wmclass:SageTerminal
app:Sage.desktop
Can I paste a screenshot into a comment?

@RichardQuint Don't bother! I was just curious whether the right WM_CLASS was showing up correctly using lg. I honestly don't know that's the deal with my installation then (it's also a VM that I've barely touched, no weird configurations, no nothing), but I guess since egmont also ran into problems, there must be something more to this issue in general. Well at least it's fixed for you, which is something!
